# Preferred Python (or any language, really) style: Should else be used when if returns?

Tags: coding-style, python

Very simple question:

Specifically in Python (since Python actually has "strongly recommended" style guidelines specified in [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), but really this applies to any language), should a function with an `if` clause that always returns have the alternative code in an `else` clause or not?  In other words, `func_style_one()` and `func_style_two()` in the following piece of code are (obviously) exactly equivalent:

```
def func_style_one():
    if some_conditional_function():
        do_something()
        return something()
    else:
        do_something_else()
        return something_else()

def func_style_two():
    if some_conditional_function():
        do_something()
        return something()
    do_something_else()
    return something_else()
```

Obviously, the best and most readable style depends on the situation, and *opinions* will vary greatly on which is better, but I'm asking which is specifically preferred by the core Python community. (e.g. Which is used more often in the standard library, all other things being equal?)

Comment: I tend to pick the second one

Comment: I think the second is safer.  Less prone to changing an else to an elif during a refactor and accidentally creating a code path with no return value.

Comment: If all the equivalent of the else does is return, then the first. If the else does additional computation - the second.

Comment: I use `else` if the two options are equal, but I drop it if the `if` part is meant to be an unlikely result, for instance with a similar function to an assertion.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @AndrewGorcester I think you and I are pretty much on the same wave-length on this one then...

Comment: Yeah, and maybe my idea of this is more clear if I put it this way... If removing the `if` block entire would ever make sense, then leave off the `else`.  That way you can, in fact, easily remove the `if` block.  But if `if` and `else` are both totally integral and one makes no sense without the other, then keep the `else`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Python, should I use else after a return in an if block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033906/in-python-should-i-use-else-after-a-return-in-an-if-block)

Comment: @Wooble: Thanks for the link.  It does appear to be a bit of a duplicate (but, of course, StackOverflow is so massive that I couldn't find that after searching for a bit).  I'm trying to ask something slightly different and a bit more definite that "which do you prefer", which is why that question was closed.  I'm asking "which *is* preferred", a subtle but important difference.

Comment: You ask "which is preferred by the community" but then accept an answer that is just one person's opinion? Doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I am open to other responses, but I wanted to reward the user who made a clean and reasonably complete response.  If someone offers a better response, I'd be willing to change the accepted status.  (Not sure if this is the standard etiquette on StackOverflow, but I do know it's generally rude to not accept an answer when a reasonably complete one has been given, or at least so I've been told)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you should always avoid adding unneccessary complexity to your code, whatever the language. It also often is a good idea to try to split your code into semantically meaninful subsections.

Given these heuristics, there is no definitive answer. It really boils down to what you are trying to achieve.

I'll demonstrate this with examples.

If we have a function that checks for various error conditions before proceeding, it could make sense to write it without `else`:

```
def do_stuff():
    if error1():
        return cleanup_and_fail()
    return ok()
```

This is better as you often end up checking several errors in similar fashion in a sequence:

```
def do_stuff():
    if error1():
        return cleanup_and_fail()
    if error2():
        return do_different_cleanup_and_fail()
    return ok()
```

However, if your function instead branches to two equal branches, it could semantically make more sense to you else:

```
def do_stuff():
    if option1():
        return do_option1()
    else:
        return do_option2()
```

This is because you often end up adding several other options with `elif`:

```
def do_stuff():
    if option1():
        return do_option1()
    elif:
        return do_option2()
    else:
        return do_option3()
```

To summarize: think about the semantics of your code and choose syntax accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This is typically what I do, I was just wondering if there was any consensus, e.g. WWGD (what would Guido do?).  But it's good to know that other programmers think similarly.

Comment: At least I think so. Also I really appreciate that you are embracing PEP 8 - people read style guides way too little. However, style guides are always soft rules - if the problem in hand requires you to deviate from them, then you should. For instance if you are extending a Python app with Java-like naming conventions, it may be better to use that convention instead of what PEP 8 strictly suggests.

Comment: For trivial conditional returns like you give here, I think a mapping mechanism (`options = ['opt1', 'opt'2]   return options[opt]`) is both clearer and more maintainable.  With more complex conditionals, especially with further nested conditions within conditions, it can quickly become difficult to ensure every code path has a return value, hence why having the last line of the method be a catchall default return keeps things easier to manage in the long run.  Of course, if a default makes no sense contextually, you shouldn't have one, but then `else` makes no sense either.

Comment: I don't disagree with you. However that doesn't counter my point that is being there is no definitive answer to this question. Granted that I too would prefer using the elseless solution in many occasions.