# if else return practice

Tags: python

Noob question I know, but I need it confirmed since this occurs so often to me. Is there any point in using `elif:` if you know that code won't be reached when previous block is true? Eg.

```
if foo:
  return x
elif bar:
  return y
```

Should just be:

```
if foo:
  return x
if bar:
  return y
```

Comment: I don't see a need to use elif in that case, but styleguides could say otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see at least three reasons to prefer `if/elif`:

- It makes it clear to readers of the code that the writer intended the conditions to be mutually exclusive
- If the code is later refactored, changing early returns to a single late return, the semantics of `if/elif` won't break, but `if/if` might
- It keeps the code style consistent with the rest of the codebase you're working in

and at least two reasons to prefer `if/if`:

- It's less typing
- It keeps the code style consistent with the rest of the codebase you're working in

That said, here's some recommended reading:

- [Should I return from a function early or use an if statement?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement)
- [Python Guide. Code Style - Returning values](https://python-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing/style/#returning-values)
- [In Python, should I use else after a return in an if block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033906/in-python-should-i-use-else-after-a-return-in-an-if-block) (take this one with a healthy pinch of salt)

Comment: Adding to the first point, 'Explicit is better than implicit' -- line 2, [*The Zen of Python*](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: @Volatility I feel the `return` statements are very explicit either way.

Comment: @JanneKarila I was talking about the 'mutually exclusive' part `;)`

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any difference to the python interpreter; in fact, the two code snippets will internally compile to the same instructions (the compiler is smart enough to know that the code after the return will never be reached, and will optimize the `else` part away completely.).

It's a matter of style, and readability.

Answer (score 1):

From the standpoint of the Python interpreter, no, there's no difference--or at least, there's no difference in terms of execution, though there may be some subtle difference in the way the two constructs are implemented.

But keep in mind that you are writing not just to the interpreter; you're writing for other programmers to read your code later. Write whatever you think makes your intention most clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you know it won't be true, then don't waste the interpreter's time with checking it.  If you use `if` it will be evaluated every time; however, `elif` will only be evaluated if the previous `if` condition was `False`.  In this case you are using `return`, so you should be safe from that, but by changing logical flow based on a return is bad.  You should have as few (preferably only one) code paths as possible.  Also, it gives a clean, readable structure and makes the code path explicit.  Readability counts, and explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: The question was `Is there any point in using elif: if you know that code won't be reached when previous block is true?`  His `return` was an example, so I provided an explanation considering other possibilities as well.  For the sake of clarity I have modified my answer.

Comment: The question is clearly about `if you know that code won't be reached` not about `when the condition in the second code block isn't true` -- if it isn't reached, no time can be wasted.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple `IF` statements means your code will check all the `IF` conditions, whereas in case of `elif:`, if one `IF` condition satisfies it would not check other conditions. (As has been pointed out to me, this is ONLY true if none of the `IF` statements has to `return` from the code block)

In your case, it is OK to use the multiple `IF` statement.

Comment: I don't think that's necessarily true. If the function returns early, the interpreter shouldn't ever get to the next `if`.

Comment: Multiple `if` statements, in which the function *has* to return from the code block, won't affect the interpreter at all.